# getting input from libgosu in ruby

Tags: ruby, libgosu

there's a method that you can check 'the key' user are pressing:

```
Gosu.button_down? id
```

the id parameter can be Gosu::KB_UP, Gosu::KB_1, Gosu::KB_F1...
but is there any method that you can get id of the key the user are pressing?

Comment: The id parameter returns an integer. You can check what those are against a hash. You can refer here for all ids - https://github.com/gosu/gosu/blob/cdd0397092432f1058c6404c543a823579c1e311/Gosu/Buttons.hpp

Answer (score 0):

There's a method called `button_down(id)`, you need to override it.

```
class Window < Gosu::Window
   def button_down(id)
     puts id
   end
end
```